# KVO on outside class not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, key-value-observing

I have a MainViewController with NSString property currentTag. So I do:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTag" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

and this works fine, and the changes do get handled properly. However, I have another class SecondViewController, and I also want it to observe MainViewController's currentTag, so in the SecondViewController's viewDidLoad method, I do:

```
[self addObserver:self.mainViewController forKeyPath:@"currentTag" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

However, this one doesn't get handled for some reason. It never gets called. I want to make sure my syntax and form is correct before looking elsewhere in my code for the problem. Does this code seem ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, you should do:

```
[self.mainViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentTag" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```